# How to graph a level set of $f(x,y)=\sqrt{4-x^2-y^2}$?

Tags: graphing-functions

If the definitions are:

$$D=\{(x,y) \in\mathbb{R}^2 \mid x^2+y^2<4\}$$

$$f:D\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$$

$$f(x,y)=\sqrt{4-x^2-y^2}$$

How do I graph the contour line (subset of $D$) where $f(x,y)=c$ with a real constant $c > 0$?

I'm using a mac, so I've got the *Grapher* app at my disposal. Any help on how I can do this would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Let $c\in(0,2]$. The equation $f(x,y)=c$ is:

$$\sqrt{4-x^2-y^2}=c.$$

Squaring both sides:

$$4-x^2-y^2=c^2.$$

Rearranging
$$x^2+y^2=4-c^2.$$

This is the circle of radius $\sqrt{4-c^2}$ centred at the origin.